# Formatting bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using bootstrap timepicker (http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) and want to format the default value this way: 00:00 but there is only one leading zero in my solution:

[image: Timepicker without leading zero]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input type="text" id="timepicker1" class="input-small bookingTextBox" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker(
{
    minuteStep: 1,
    showMeridian: false,
    defaultTime: '00:00'
});
```

Is there a way to show 00:00 as default value?

Answer (score 1):

check on this link for help for you [click here](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

try this

> defaultTime : '00:00 AM'

Comment: Unforunately this does not work. It still shows 0:00